# Get complete hours time_buckets with timescaledb

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am trying to use timescaledb time_buckets to get an aggregated energy use per hour. The problem is that these hourly buckets do not take into account the record after exactly one full hour. So from the sample data below the bucket at 00:00 only takes into account 00:00 till 00:45 while I want it to also include the 01:00. And the second bucket should take into account the same 01:00 till 02:00.

```
---------------------------------------------
| datetime          | energy_use_total      |
---------------------------------------------
| 2023-07-26 00:00  | 100                   |
| 2023-07-26 00:15  | 125                   |
| 2023-07-26 00:30  | 150                   |
| 2023-07-26 00:45  | 175                   |
| 2023-07-26 01:00  | 200                   |
| 2023-07-26 01:15  | 210                   |
| 2023-07-26 01:30  | 220                   |
| 2023-07-26 01:45  | 230                   |
| 2023-07-26 02:00  | 240                   |
---------------------------------------------
```

The result should be:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| bucket            | period_begin      | period_end        | energy_use_total_processed |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2023-07-26 00:00  | 2023-07-26 00:00  | 2023-07-26 01:00  | 100                        |
| 2023-07-26 01:00  | 2023-07-26 01:00  | 2023-07-26 02:00  |  40                        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to achieve this with time_buckets? I tried the following query but that gave me the result below the query:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW electricity_hourly
WITH (timescaledb.continuous)
AS SELECT
    time_bucket('1 h'::interval, datetime) as bucket,   
    first(datetime, datetime) as period_begin,
    last(datetime, datetime) as period_end,
    MAX(energy_use_total) - MIN(energy_use_total) as energy_use_total_processed
FROM source_table 
GROUP BY 1;
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| bucket            | period_begin      | period_end        | energy_use_totat_processed |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2023-07-26 00:00  | 2023-07-26 00:00  | 2023-07-26 00:45  | 75                         |
| 2023-07-26 01:00  | 2023-07-26 01:00  | 2023-07-26 01:45  | 30                         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see the value on the whole hour at the end is excluded. Is it possible to have a certain overlap in buckets or get the last value from the previous bucket? Or is there another way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A time bucket end, in TimescaleDB, is always exclusive, meaning a one hour time bucket creates buckets such as `00:00 - 00:59:59.999999`, `01:00 - 01:59:59.999999`, and so on. That said, TimescaleDB doesn't support overlapping time windows, at least not out of the box.

If you change your continuous aggregate by adding a column keeping the first value for every time bucket, you can kind of simulate it though.

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW electricity_hourly
WITH (timescaledb.continuous)
AS SELECT
    time_bucket('1 h'::interval, datetime) as bucket,   
    first(datetime, datetime) as period_begin,
    last(datetime, datetime) as period_end,
    first(energy_use_total, datetime) as first_value,
    MAX(energy_use_total) - MIN(energy_use_total) as energy_use_total_processed
FROM source_table 
GROUP BY 1;
```

Now you can query it with something like the following (may not work exactly like it but something along the lines):

```sql
SELECT
  bucket,
  period_begin,
  LAG(period_begin) OVER (ORDER BY bucket) AS period_end,
  GREATEST(
    energy_use_total, 
    LAG(first_value) OVER (ORDER BY bucket)
  ) - LEAST(
    energy_use_total,
    LAG(first_value) OVER (ORDER BY bucket)
  ) AS energy_use_total_processed
FROM electricity_hourly
```

To make it real nice, you could put the above query into a normal view, which will make it nicely queryable, just as you'd have it available directly.